# how to get each and every Date in between selected date (in DB2)

Tags: date, db2, date-range

Dear StackOverflow Community,

as a New to DB2 ,i have a a query 
may be its a very basic question for you, please share your knowledge.

i have a start date and End Date.
I need a list of each and every date in between.

Its ok with me ,if it creates a temp table no issue. 
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

You can generate the dates between start and end dates by using Recursive CTE expression. Try below code

```
    with cte(your_columns,startdate,enddate)
    as (select your_columns,startdate,enddate,startdate 
as derDate
    from yourTable
    union all
    select your_columns,startdate,enddate,derDate+1 
    from cte where 
    derDate<=endDate)
    select * from cte
```

Comment: Finally I'm starting to understand cte with union all.   one quick edit please derdate < enddate otherwise it goes past